# Splitting strings based on Uppercase

Tags: r, regex

I am pretty new to Regex. I have transcript data that look something like:

```
Senator GRASSLEY. blah blah blah. Senator CRUZ. blah blah blah.
```

What I am trying to do is to create a data.frame where "Senator GRASSLEY" and "Senator Cruz" is assigned into a column called "speaker" and "blah blah blah" are turned into rows in a column called "text". How would I go about doing this? I am not sure what would be the best way to go about this.

EDIT: the word "Senator" does not always need to be matched to the name (e.g. GRASSLEY does not always need to match Senator).

EDIT: Here's a better example of the data I am working with here. The names in all uppercase is meant to identify who is speaking.

> 

2 Chairman GRASSLEY [continuing]. Their two daughters—— Senator KLOBUCHAR. Mr. Chairman, I agree with my colleague, Senator Harris. Chairman GRASSLEY [continuing]. And their family and friends—— Senator KLOBUCHAR. Mr. Chairman, we received 42,000 docu- ments—— Chairman GRASSLEY [continuing]. Judge Kavanaugh’s many law clerks—— Senator KLOBUCHAR [continuing]. That we have not been able to review last night. Chairman GRASSLEY [continuing]. And everyone else joining us today. Senator KLOBUCHAR. And we believe this hearing should be post- poned. Chairman GRASSLEY. I know this is an exciting day for all of you here—— Senator BLUMENTHAL. Mr. Chairman. Chairman GRASSLEY [continuing]. And you are rightly proud of Judge—— Senator BLUMENTHAL. Mr. Chairman, if we cannot be recognized, I move to adjourn. Chairman GRASSLEY. The American people—— Senator BLUMENTHAL. Mr. Chairman, I move to adjourn. [Disturbance in the hearing room.] Chairman GRASSLEY [continuing]. Will hear directly from Judge Kavanaugh later this afternoon. Senator BLUMENTHAL. Mr. Chairman, I move to adjourn. [Disturbance in the hearing room.] Senator BLUMENTHAL. Mr. Chairman, we have been denied—we have been denied real access to the documents we need to advise and consent—— Senator CORNYN. Mr. Chairman, regular order is called for. Senator BLUMENTHAL [continuing]. Which turns this hearing into a charade and a mockery of our norms. Chairman GRASSLEY. Well—— Senator BLUMENTHAL. And, Mr. Chairman, I, therefore, move to adjourn this hearing. Chairman GRASSLEY. Okay. [Disturbance in the hearing room.] Senator BLUMENTHAL. Mr. Chairman, I ask for a roll call vote on my motion to adjourn. Chairman GRASSLEY. Okay. Senator BLUMENTHAL. Mr. Chairman, I move to adjourn. I ask for a roll call vote. Chairman GRASSLEY. We are not in executive session. We will continue as planned. Senator BOOKER. Mr. Chairman, may I be recognized, sir? Mr. Chairman, I appeal to the Chair to recognize myself or one of my colleagues. Chairman GRASSLEY. You are out of order. Senator BOOKER. Mr. Chairman, I appeal to be recognized on your sense of decency and integrity. Even the documents you have requested, Mr. Chairman, even the ones that you said, the limited

Comment: What is your expected match? `GRASSLEY` and `CRUZ`? `Senator GRASSLEY` and `Senator CRUZ`? In the latter case, is the preceding word always Senator? Does the preceeding word always need to be matched?

Comment: No, sorry the proceeding word does not always need to match. Thanks for asking for clarification.

Comment: Do you have a single long string or several shorter strings?  Do you have a list of senator names?  Is "blah" ever something like "ETA" or "USMC"?

Comment: I don't know about `r` programming but this could work `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+( [A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)*` https://regex101.com/r/4ANdby/1/

Comment: The string length varies a lot.

Comment: @Limey No, I don't see any fully capitalized things that should be in the text column. Just the names.

Comment: Grabbing upper case words can be done via `\b[A-Z]+\b` (https://regex101.com/r/lD2TLR/1), though I'm not sure if that is all that is required in this case as a simple `str_split` would not give you a way to retrieve the match, if I read the documentation correctly. Unfortunately not familiar with R, so I can't help you much with that part.

Comment: Are the names always ended with a `.`? As you have multiple names, some fully capitalized some not, extracting them is not "simple". Regex basically is looking for a pattern and "I am looking for one or more words that contains at least one or more capitalized letters in both words" is not really specific enough. Don't misunderstand me, it could be done, but it would be regex+followup checking the words. Even if they are all ending with a dot, expect the need for a multi-step process..

Comment: @Oliver You're right that there are some like Senator Cruz and not Senator CRUZ. I am wanting to separate the strings for only the names that are all caps. Re: punctuation. Yes, the names that I want to separate by are always followed by a period. Unfortunately the transcript formatting uses periods instead of colons. The capitalization of names is what is distinct.

Comment: please provide some better sample data and a derired output. Make use of `dput()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for the text you used as an example. As discussed in the comments it is not a process that just "works with regex" rather you need to consider a multi-step process. Extract the words you need and then extract the text.

In this case the regex becomes quite hard to read (for my eyes at least) so I did it one step at a time, detailed in the comments.

I go with base-R here, because I want to use the result in a multi-step process but you could have used the interface provided by `stringr` as well.

```
str <- "Senator GRASSLEY. blah blah blah. Senator CRUZ. blah blah blah."
# use gregexpr to find word positions
positions <- gregexpr('\\b[A-Z]+[A-Za-z]*(\\b\\s*\\b[A-Za-z]*)*\\.', str)[[1]]
# regex detailed explanation (note \\ instead of \ because we need to escape "\" in R strings):
# \\b = word boundary
# [A-Z]+ any non-zero capitalized word or letter.
# =>   \\b[A-Z]+ -> any capitalizd word after a word boundary
# [A-Za-z]*\\b any sequence of letters (possibly length 0 because of *) ended by a word-boundary
# => \\b[A-Z]+[A-Za-z]*\\b  any word with one or more starting capitalized letters
# \\s* Any number of spaces between words.
# \\b[A-Za-z]*\\. any word ending with a dot.
# 
# => (\\b\\s*\\b[A-Za-z]*)* any number of potentially capitalized.
# 
# Translated:
# Match any sequence of words where the first word has a starting capital letter
# any all of the following words may be capitalized fully or partialyl
# End when you find a "."
match_lengths <- attr(positions, "match.length")
n_matches <- length(positions)
# Extract the matches
names <- substring(str, positions, positions + match_lengths - 1) # -1 because the "start + length = end + 1"
# Extract text in between matches.

text_starts <- positions + match_lengths
text_ends <- c(positions[-1] - 1, nchar(str))
text <- substring(str, 
                  text_starts, 
                  text_ends)

data.frame(names = names, text = text)
              names              text
1 Senator GRASSLEY.  blah blah blah. 
2     Senator CRUZ.   blah blah blah.
```

Note there is some "whitespace" in `text` that could be removed and I have not removed the dot in names (I could've substracted 2 in the first substring instead if i wanted to).

Be wary though, there is no guarantee this accounts for all the details in your data, but it might get your started.

Comment: This should work. Thank you. Apologies for my ignorance on this. Appreciate the patience.

Comment: My pleasure, and don't worry. We have all been there, and the tone in the comments could've been better. We only learn by bashing our head face first into the wall while programming, and no question is stupid as long as they show some effort.